# Hostname for Amazon Glacier on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

What is the Hostname / Servername for Amazon AWS Glacier?

S3 is: s3.amazonaws.com 
I can find the ARN (Amazon Resource Name) in my console, but cannot find a hostname or reference to it (in the context of Glacier) in the [AWS docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/amazon-glacier-getting-started.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't look hard enough :)

glacier.*Region*.amazonaws.com

The hostname value must be of the form "glacier.region.amazonaws.com", where region is replaced with a region designation such as us-east-1.

See [the documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-common-request-headers.html) :)

Comment: You're welcome. You could show your appreciation by marking it as the answer ;)